# RxJS interval() varies wildly in MS Edge

Tags: timer, rxjs, intervals, polling

I have an Angular 6 application that performs an API call every 10 seconds to update price quotes.  The timing of the API calls is manages using RxJS interval().

For some reason, on MS Edge, the timings vary wildly, from a couple of seconds, to minutes.  Any ideas what might be the cause?

Here is the code:

```
const refreshPriceInterval = interval(10000);
let startTime = new Date(), endTime: Date;

refreshPriceInterval.pipe(
        startWith(0),
        flatMap(() => {
            endTime = new Date();
            let timeDiff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime(); //in ms
            // strip the ms
            timeDiff /= 1000;
            console.log(timeDiff);
            startTime = new Date();
            return this.timeseriesService.getQuote(symbol, this.userInfo.apiLanguage);
        })
)
```

Here is the console output:

```
0.001
18.143
4.111
11.057
13.633
12.895
3.003
12.394
7.336
31.616
20.221
10.461
```

Is there a way to increase the accuracy?

EDIT:

Performance degrades over time.

Reducing the code in the interval() to only a console.log does not perform any better.

Might be an Angular issue.

Comment: What is your CPU load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed an Angular issue.  Timed processes cause Angular to constantly re-render the app, which can be quite resource intensive.

I used [runOutsideAngular()](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runoutsideangular) to circumvent this issue.  It turned out that I only had to run one function outside of Angular:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.handleMouseEvents();
});
```

Thanks to Mark van Straten for your input!

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the browser to decide how many CPU cycles are allocated per browser tab. Depending on resources (for instance; battery) or activity (background tab vs foreground tab) your browser page will receive more or less cpu slices.

some background: https://github.com/WICG/interventions/issues/5

> This is shipped in Edge as well now (as of EdgeHTML14). The clamping to 1Hz in background tabs, not anything more intensive.

Apart from this fact; you are measuring the latency of your call as well: 
`timeseriesService.getQuote()` so it might also be that this call just takes some time.

Comment: I have heard that there are inherent limitations to setTimeout.  However, this is really off.  In fact, I have noticed that consistency degrades over time!

I also tried the interval with only a console output, which performed no better.

Here is some later output:

34.192
17.981
14.597
23.412
20.509
43.581
54.677
18.835
67.185
68.983
100.294
17.076

So much for 10 seconds!

I wonder if it could it be an Angular issue?